# is anyone still using parse-server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

the prerequisites list

Node 4.3 - while the current version is 8.12
also 
MongoDB version 2.6.X, 3.0.X or 3.2.X  is listed  while latest version is 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking at an old version.
parse-server is under very active development.
The current version (3.0.0) needs Node >= 8 and MongoDB support is at least v3.4.13.

Comment: Yeah, that hasn’t been updated in a while. You should look at the package itself.